# Simple web server when high-concurrency is met

Tags: java, concurrency

This is not a homework, but an interview question that I found on the web.

The java code is:

```
public class SimpleWebServer{
  public static void handleRequest(Socket c)
  {
    //Process the request
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  { 
    ServerSocket server=new ServerSocket(80);
    while(true)
    {
       final Socket connection=server.accept();
       Runnable task=new Runnable(){
          @Override
          public void run()
          {
            handleRequest(connection);
          }
       };
       new Thread(task).start();
    }
  }
}
```

The question is what potential issue there will be when there is a high concurrency? My analysis is :

1. It didn't use synchronized keyword, so there might be situations that race-condition happen.
2. It should use a thread pool, which is more efficient.
3. It seems like for each incoming thread, the class always creates a new ServerSocket, which will consume a lot of space when high-concurrency happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem that I see with this, is the one you've identified. The thread-per-request model is inherently flawed (as evidenced by widescale adoption of Nginx and lighttpd over Apache). Moving to an ExecutorService (probably backed by a thread pool) would be a good choice here.

By changing from a thread-per-request to a simple submission of a task to an ExecutorService, you are moving this application towards an event-based model. There's a lot of material out on the web preaching the scalability virtues of event-based over thread-based models.

Using 'synchronized' on the `handleRequest` method is a pretty brute-force tactic, and depending on the particular guts of the method a more granular locking strategy (or lock-free logic) would be preferred. The ServerSocket creation you mentioned only happens once for the application, so that's not really a scalability problem. The `accept` method does create a new `Socket` instance for each connection, but these are cheap. Looking at the JDK 6 source, this consists of allocating 7 booleans, a lock `Object`, and checking some internal state - i.e., probably not going to be a problem.

Basically, you're on the right track! Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here are list of potential problems

1) Spawning a thread takes CPU cycles and each thread had its own data structures that consumes memory. When one thread blocks, JVM saves its state and selects another thread to run, and restore state of chosen thread, it is called *context switch*. As number of threads increase, more resources are consumed by threads. Threadpool was introduced to solve this problem by limiting number of threads and reusing threads instead of spawning new ones.

2) The most frustrating and important issue is to make these threads share or access a variable (e.g. state) in synchronised fashion. It is easy to make these variables inconsistent. Therefore, some programmers prefer to use single threaded environment (e.g. NIO) instead of multi threaded environment.

3) Having no logging system is going to make threaded environment extra harder to debug when you want to trace down a problem.

4) You do not need to instantiate new serversocket() every time when you want to accept a new client since it is a shared Serversocket instance.